# Key Error for total_count in the API response

Tags: python, rest, pyspark, pagination

I am trying a Python code to do pagination of API calls to loop through pages. When I do a postman call I get correct response and page info like below:

```
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "abcd",
        "created_by": "abc",
        "created_at": "2023-10-06",
        "modified_by": "oabc",
        "modified_at": "2023-10-07",
        "row_state_id": "",
        "is_archived": false,
 ---------------------------------
  -----------------------    
 "page_info": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 100,
    "total_pages": 5200,
    "total_count": 520066
```

I am attempting to loop through each of pages to get data and collect in a list. My Python code is below:

```
def make_api_call(getURL, params={}):
   response = requests.get(getURL, params=params, headers=headers)
   response.raise_for_status()
   return response.json()

def paginate_results(api_call, total_pages):
   results = []
   for page_number in range(1, total_pages + 1):
     params = {'page': page_number}
     response = api_call(params=params)
     results.extend(response['data'])
return results
```

## Get the total number of pages

```
getURL = 'https://example.com/v1/users'
response = make_api_call(getURL)

total_pages = response['total_count'] // response['per_page'] + 1
```

## paginate through the results

```
results = paginate_results(make_api_call, total_pages)
```

Throwing below error. Any help appreciated to fix the issue

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [87], line 39
    36 getURL = 'https://example.com/v1/users'
    37 response = make_api_call(getURL)
    ---> 39 total_pages = response['total_count'] // response['per_page'] + 1
    41 #paginate through the results
    42 results = paginate_results(make_api_call, total_pages)

KeyError: 'total_count'
```

Comment: Try to debug it by printing response and cross verify that you are accessing proper key.
based on Postman output provided above you may have to access it like `response['page_info']['total_count']`. if it doesn't work then please also provide the output you are getting when printing response.

Comment: @Hetvi -thank you i added like you said and it worked. But issue iam facing now is with total count of many pages the code is taking like 3 hrs. How can i modify the code to write those with total count after each page iterations instead of collecting data from every page and writing?